# Why in many codes written "if try catch"?

Tags: java, syntax, syntax-error

Why in many codes written like as:

```
finally{
if(out!=null){
try{out.close();}
catch(){}
}}
```

But not:

```
finally{
try{out.close();}
catch(){}
}
```

Comment: Because if `out == null`, you'll get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: what happened when you tried this?

Comment: not to mention that 
catch(){} will not occur. you need to specify what you catch.
also:
catch(xxException e){}
should not occur in 'many codes' , since hiding problems doesn't solve them.

Comment: `try...catch` is not required in first case,not null check will do the job.

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar try-catch should be required here, as closing a stream could throw an `IOException`

Comment: To avoid null pointer exception, we are checking that condition

Comment: @user3580294 Than not null check is not required !!! `NullPointer` can be handled in `catch`. (Please, correct me again if I am wrong)

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar An explicit null pointer check is better handled in an `if` statement than as an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you want to create some kind of stream. This creation could fail, e.g. because a file is missing or an internet connection is not working. So you need to put it into a try-catch-block because it throws a check-exception which you need to handle:

```
Stream stream = null;
try {
    stream = makeNewStream();
    // more stuff
} catch(SomeException e) {
    // do something with the exception
}
```

Now you want to be sure, that the stream is closed in the end, no matter what happens. So you add a finally block:

```
Stream stream = null;
try {
    stream = makeNewStream();
    // more stuff
} catch(SomeException e) {

} finally {
    stream.close()
}
```

This block will be called in any case, even if your code fails (e.g. `stream = makeNewStream();` throws an exception). But if `stream = makeNewStream();` throws an exception, the variable `stream` will be null. So you need to check if stream is null (you cannot call a method on null ;):

```
finally {
    if(stream != null)
        stream.close()
}
```

Now, unfortunately, `close()` will also throw a checked-exception (which need to be handled), so you have to check this too. And you will end up with something like this:

```
Stream stream = null;
try {
    stream = makeNewStream();
    // more stuff
} catch(SomeException e) {

} finally {
    if(stream != null) {
        try {
            stream.close()
        } catch(ClosingException e) {
            // ignore this
        }
    }
}
```

Most developers will just ignore the last exception in the finally block.